# Copy log cannot copy complete information in Wix installer

Tags: wix

I am facing an issue in Copy log file in Wix installer. Actually I used custom action to copy log to specified location and same worked in my local machine, but fails in Server machine. Both in X64. In Server, few lines especially completion status is being missed in copied file, but when we look temp folder in server, we could find the complete log.

Can someone help me on this to overcome.

Comment: How are you doing the log copying?

Comment: <CustomAction Id="CopyLog" Execute="immediate" ExeCommand="cmd /c copy [MsiLogFileLocation] [CURRENTDIRECTORY]\Setup.log" Directory="TARGETDIR" Impersonate="no" Return="asyncNoWait" />